# Getting next element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have markup like this:

```
<div>
  <a href="#">show</a>
</div>
<div class="msg" style="display: none;">message</div>

<div>
  <a href="#">show</a>
</div>
<div class="msg" style="display: none;">message</div>

<div>
  <a href="#">show</a>
</div>
<div class="msg" style="display: none;">message</div>
```

I want to show the 'msg' when the parent link is clicked.

Here's what I have:

```
$('a').click(function(){

   $(this).next('.msg').show();

});
```

However this doesn't work, doesn't do anything.  Any suggestions?

Thank you!

EDIT:

This is the exact markup:

```
<div class="left">
    <a href="/checkout/" class="overlay_box no_thanks">&#171; Back</a>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <button type="submit" class="button link" href="'.$item->click_url.'">
    <span>'.$this->lang->line('next').'</span></button>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<br/>
<div class="message" style="display: none;">
    <img src="/assets/img/icon.png" class="left"/>
    <p class="left"><b>Complete?</b> Once you have completed (<a href="/help">Help</a>)</p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
```

The click event is on the button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().nextAll('.message:first').show();
```

Since the link is the only element within a div, it has no siblings, so next() returns an empty set for it. You need to get the parent element and call next() for it.

Comment: I changed it, I have $(this).parent().next('.message').show();

Comment: Even then it would not work. @dave: If you have markup question, post the real markup from the beginning.

Comment: @dave: Use `$(this).parent().nextAll('.message:first').show();`

Comment: @Evgeny - Thank you as well, sorry for the incorrect markup to start.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because the `<a>` element is not the parent of the `'.msg'` element - it's actually a child of its sibling.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, target the parent of the `<a>`, like this: `$('a').closest('div').next('.msg').show()`.
If it's only to show an element and you don't want to navigate to another page then prevent the natural behaviour of the `<a>` tag by adding `.preventDefault()` or `return false`. They both work. Like this:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
   $(this).closest('div').next('.msg').show();

   e.preventDefault();
});
```

You could have used:

```
$('a').parent().next()...
```

But apparently the below is more efficient:

```
$('a').closest( tag ).next()...
```